# Update original Mono when error occurs in chain

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

Suppose I have something like this:

```
Mono.just(a)
    .flatMap(...) // init
    // set fields on a if error occurs
    .flatMap(...) // finalize
    .subscribe();
```

In the last `flatMap` I'm executing some final logic depending on value of fields in `a`. In particular I need to know if an error occurred during init...

So I need a method that will intercept errors and permit to manipulate original object.

If I'm not wrong, all `onError*` methods return the original object without permitting updating it.

Also `doOnError` doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind this is a chain of discrete and (potentially) asynchronous steps. Once you've entered a step, the only context you get is the previous step's output in the form of the `onNext`, `onComplete` and `onError` signals, plus whatever java core language feature can expose to you. For example, if you're assembling an inner `Flux` in a `flatmap` lambda, java gives you access to that lambda's input parameters.

The later might be the solution to what you need: a scope in which you can get hold of the original value.

So that first `flatMap` can act as that enclosing scope and deal with both nominal and error cases. Something like:

```
Mono<B> processed = Mono.just(a)
    .flatMap(a -> init(a)
        .onErrorResume(fallback(a))
    )
    .flatMap(...); // finalize
processed.subscribe();

//for illustration purposes, what process and fallback may typically look like:
Mono<B> init(A a) {
    return Mono.zip(
        asyncServiceStuff.process(a.stuff),
        asyncServiceOtherStuff.process(a.otherStuff),
        (bPart1, bPart2) -> new B(bPart1, bPart2)
    );
}

Mono<B> fallback(A original) {
    return Mono.just(new FallbackB(a.otherStuff));
}
```

That said, it seems that you want to create the fallback from `a`, which is already accessible within the *scope* of the method (ideally as a `final` input parameter or variable).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fact that every single next reactive operator build for us a new `Mono` instance. So, it is not going to matter for you if you add one more operator:

```
/**
 * Simply emit a captured fallback value when any error is observed on this {@link Mono}.
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/onErrorReturnForMono.svg" alt="">
 *
 * @param fallback the value to emit if an error occurs
 *
 * @return a new falling back {@link Mono}
 */
public final Mono<T> onErrorReturn(final T fallback) {

Mono.just(a)
    .flatMap(...)
    .onErrorReturn(fallbackValue)
    .flatMap(...)
    .subscribe();
```

You definitely can investigate all other `onError*` for any possible error handling variants.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer. In my case the `fallbackValue` should be created from the information retrieved in the original a object and the throwable intercepted from the `onError`(?) method. So basically I need a Mono method similar to `onErrorDoSomething(Throwable t, Mono<T> mono)` and returning a Mono<T>

Comment: OK. Then `onErrorResume()` can help you. BTW the `flatMap()` returns `Mono` as well, so you can nest such an `onError*`  in that `flatMap()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mono.just(a)
    .flatMap(...) // init
    // set fields on a if error occurs
    .onErrorResume(getFallbackMono(a))
    .flatMap(...) // finalize
    .subscribe();
```

...

```
private Mono<ClassOfA> getFallbackMono(ClassOfA a) {
    return Mono.just(getMutatedA(a));
}
```

`.onErrorResume` will return a stream to fallback on. Here, you can create a new stream with the mutated value of `a`.

`.doOnError()` is a side-effect operator. I would use it to log the error.